# How to programmatically paste from service to foreground app?

Tags: android

What I'm trying to do is to paste some text from a service inside edittext that has the focus (and belongs to another app). Is there a way to do this?

Comment: Yes, there are several ways in fact (AIDL, Intents, Messenger, TCP...). Just go read the docs.

Comment: @m0skit0 - yes, if the poster has cooperation of the author of the other app, but it appears that they do not.

Comment: @ChrisStratton That definitely could be, but I don't see that specified anywhere in the question nor I'm willing to play (again) guessing games. *"Too broad"*.

Comment: no, they are not cooperating.

Comment: If you don't have the other developer's cooperation, then you have the answer below - you can't do that without the user's cooperation.